# Write to date partitioned bigQuery using a date present in the data in batch DataFlow job

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a number of text files with data that I want to import to a date-partitioned BigQuery table from a DataflowPipelineRunner running in batch mode. Instead of inserting to the partition of the current day at runtime I want to insert into a partition based on a date mentioned in each row. I am executing below program but getting error as "The method to(String) in the type BigQuery.IO.Write is not applicable for the arguments (new SerializableFunction() {)"

Program:

```
  PCollection<String> read = p.apply("Read Lines",TextIO.read().from("gs://prasadk/DataFlowGCSToBQ/employee.txt"));

  PCollection<TableRow> rows = read.apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<String,TableRow>(){
      @ProcessElement
      public void processElement(ProcessContext c)
      {
          String[] data = c.element().split(",");

          c.output(new TableRow().set("id", data[0]).set("name", data[1]).set("designation", data[2]).set("joindate", data[3]));
      }
  }));

  rows.apply(Window.<TableRow>into(CalendarWindows.days(1)))
  .apply(BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
    .withSchema(schema)
    .to(new SerializableFunction<ValueInSingleWindow<TableRow>, String>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Override
        public String apply(ValueInSingleWindow<TableRow> input) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    }));

p.run();
```

}
}

The error that I'm getting is:
The method to(String) in the type BigQueryIO.Write is not applicable for the arguments (new SerializableFunction,String>(){})

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the error is because you are using a version of Beam SDK before this function was added - it's been added in Beam 2.0.0.

Also, the signature of the function is slightly different - it takes a `ValueInSingleWindow<T>` rather than simply `BoundedWindow`: see [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/v2.0.0/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.java#L789).

Can you point to where you got the original snippet? I wonder if we have some obsolete documentation that refers to `SerializableFunction<BoundedWindow, String>`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using Beam 2.0.0 and also changed the signature of the function as per your suggestion but still facing the same issue. Please find below the link where the code is present: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/BigQueryIO

Comment: Please update the code snippet in your question with your current code, and make sure to also update and include the entire compiler error message. Looks like you also need to use BigQueryIO.writeTableRows() instead of BigQueryIO.write() because write() is for writing records of an arbitrary user-specified type, and in that case you need to also specify a function for converting the records to TableRow - but your code already writes TableRow.

Comment: I've updated my post with the latest code and the error that I'm getting. Please let me know where I'm going wrong and is this the correct way to implement this.

Comment: I am fairly sure that somehow your program is picking up the wrong version of Beam. Are you compiling this through Maven? Can you show the part of your pom.xml containing the dependency on Beam specifying the version?

Comment: I am compiling this program in Eclipse so I believe program will run through Maven. Find below requested details from pom.xml file:<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- slf4j API frontend binding with JUL backend -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.14</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: Hmm, this is very strange; it should work because Dataflow SDK 2.0 depends on Beam SDK 2.0 which absolutely has the proper method. Have you tried in Eclipse to navigate to the BigQueryIO.Write class and see what overloads of the to() method are available? Have you tried compiling your program via maven from the command line, rather than in Eclipse?

Comment: By the way, I noticed one more thing. You're specifying a SerializableFunction<ValueInSingleWindow<TableRow>, String> but it should be SerializableFunction<ValueInSingleWindow<TableRow>, TableDestination> - per https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.Write.html#to-org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.SerializableFunction- .